# Custom Actions triggered by Parsed values in Python

Tags: python, event-triggers

I am looking to build or more preferably use a framework to implement custom Assertions in python. I am listing below potential input that will be parsed to trigger the various assertions on retrieved data

```
assertValue : [ SOME STRING A ]
    or
assertValue : [ SOME STRING B ]
    or
assertValue : [ SOME STRING C ]
```

So above, when the parsed value is `"SOME STRING A"`, I would want to trigger an appropriate assertion. For eg, if the provided value is `"NOT NULL"` I would assert that retrieved data does not have NULL values in it.

The goal for the framework is to provide flexibility to add support for different Assertions and the implementations it will trigger. I tried searching for any existing frameworks that i can use for this purpose in Python. I only found event driven frameworks like "PyDispatcher" or "Django Dispatch" , which i thought is a bit over kill for this.

Has anyone come across a similar need and used something successfully. Thanks much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for something along the lines of one of [Cucumber's Python ports?](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Python)

Comment: Thanks @whats_done_is for the link. I shall study the documentation